# Keypress Event: Return another key

Tags: c#, textbox, keypress

I'm trying to build a textbox which allows only numbers and commas, in order to let its content fill an access "number" column. I used the keypress event, with the following code I made it accept numbers and dots, now I'd like to set this code to write a comma when the dot key (both from the numpad and from the keyboard) is pressed

```
private void "Mytextbox_KeyPress"(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;
        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 /*backspace*/ && ch != 46 /*canc*/ && ch != 13 /* 13=enter*/ )
        {
            e.Handled = true;
      // if ch == 110 (dot) need to return 188 (comma)
    }
```

Comment: can't really test this right now but probably doing `e.KeyChar = ',';`should be enough. according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar(v=vs.110).aspx)  `Gets or sets the character corresponding to the key pressed.`

Comment: thank you very much, adding:
            else     if (ch == '.')
            {
                e.KeyChar = ',';
            }
worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need:

```
private void Mytextbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 46)
        e.KeyChar = (char)44;
}
```

It will replace dots with commas. Don't use `e.Handled` because that will suppress the key rather than replace it.